# PHP Fatal error: Function name must be a string on line 14

Tags: php

Hi Im trying to do this simple code within a loop that does the following:
Program to write: Write a program to do the algebraic equation x = a(b+6)/2 multiple times within loops that vary a and b. The variable a should start at 1 go to 10 and increment by 1. The variable b should start at 2 and go to 10 and increment by 2. When you display the answer show the formula in php. I want you to do this three times: once with a for...next, once with a do...while and once with a while. 
I think my logic is right but Im getting the error and I cant debug.

```
<html>
<head><title>DO WHILE</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Do While</h2>
<?php

$VarA = 1;
$VarB = 2;
$VarC = 6;
$VarD = 2;
$ctA = 1;
$ctB = 2;
$VarAns = 0;
$VarAns = ($VarA ($VarB+$VarC6) / $VarD);
do 
{
$VarAns = ($VarA ($VarB+$VarC6) / $VarD);
print ("x = $VarA($VarB+6)/2 is equal to VarX<br>");
$ctA = $ctA + 1;
$ctB = $ctB + 2;
} while ($ctA <= 10 and $ctB <=10);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually i see that I messed up my Counts but thats an easy fix. I just need help with the error on line 14 which is $VarAns = ($VarA ($VarB+$VarC6) / $VarD);

Comment: No math symbols are ever assumed in programming. So while *you* see `a(b+6)/2` and automatically insert a multiplication symbol between `a` and `(`, the software does not. It assumes you are trying to run a function and the variable `a` holds the function, passing in `b+6` as an argument and then divide that return value by `2`.

Comment: Ah man that was so simple. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

On your line 14 as the title says, you have this

```
$VarAns = ($VarA ($VarB+$VarC6) / $VarD);
```

This doesnt work with PHP...

Instead write it more clearly like

```
$VarAns = $VarA * ($VarB+$VarC6) / $VarD;
```

Same thing applies to other part of your code where you use brackets like that.